# Java Spark - MySQL insert data with foreign key constrain

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, dataframe, dataset

I am trying to insert data into MYSQL DB using spark dataset/rdd.

Table A :

```
+------+------+------------------------+
| Col  | type |          desc          |
+------+------+------------------------+
| id   | int  | primary key            |
| name | text | some name              |
| b_id | int  | foreign key to table B |
+------+------+------------------------+
```

Table B :

```
+------+------+-----------------------------+
| Col  | type |            desc             |
+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id   | int  | primary key, Auto Increment |
| name | text | some name                   |
+------+------+-----------------------------+
```

I am reading data from CSV file and trying to write the data to table A but not working as to insert into A we need some id from table B (foreign key). If I create a bean A and include bean B as part of A. Will this auto create B, whenever I insert A?

Comment: It is the other way around: A is supposed to be part of B, since B is the parent, A is the child. You should import the data to B first, then to A.

Comment: @Shadow "you should import the data to B first, then to A" - can you please describe how? As `DataFrameWriter#jdbc` and `DataFrameWriter#save` are actions, and not transformations, we don't get the ids of the newly inserted rows - so how can we have them after inserting a DF of B rows, so that we may insert the A rows with their appropriate `b_id` values? I wrote a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184502/getting-the-new-row-id-from-pyspark-sql-write-to-remote-mysql-db-jdbc

Comment: @et_l no clue, I only know mysql, but not java. I can recognise a foreign key, though.