# getting the new row id from pySpark SQL write to remote mysql db (JDBC)

Tags: mysql, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark-sql to create rows in a remote mysql db, using JDBC.

I have two tables, `parent_table(id, value)` and `child_table(id, value, parent_id)`, so each row of `parent_id` may have as many rows in `child_id` associated to it as needed.

Now I want to create some new data and insert it into the database. I'm using the code guidelines [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) for the `write` opperation, but I would like to be able to do something like:

```
parentDf = sc.parallelize([5, 6, 7]).toDF(('value',))
parentWithIdDf = parentDf.write.mode('append') \
                         .format("jdbc") \
                         .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://" + host_name + "/"
                            + db_name).option("dbtable", table_name) \
                         .option("user", user_name).option("password", password_str) \
                         .save()
# The assignment at the previous line is wrong, as pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter#save doesn't return anything.
```

I would like a way for the last line of code above to return a DataFrame with the new row ids for each row so I can do

```
childDf = parentWithIdDf.flatMap(lambda x: [[8, x[0]], [9, x[0]]])
childDf.write.mode('append')...
```

meaning that at the end I would have in my remote databasde

```
parent_table
 ____________
| id | value |
 ____________
| 1  |   5   |
| 2  |   6   |
| 3  |   7   |
 ____________

child_table
 ________________________
| id | value | parent_id |
 ________________________
| 1  |   8   |    1      |
| 2  |   9   |    1      |
| 3  |   8   |    2      |
| 4  |   9   |    2      |
| 5  |   8   |    3      |
| 6  |   9   |    3      |
 ________________________
```

As I've written in the first code snippet above, `pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter#save` doesn't return anything, looking at [its documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter), so how can I achieve this?

Am I doing something completely wrong? It looks like there is no way to get data back from a Spark's action (which `save` is) while I would like to use this action as a transformation, shich leads me to think I may be thinking of all this in the wrong way.

Comment: Not possible. Also an issue wigh most dbmss.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is to to use the timestamp + auto increment number to create a unique ID. This only works if there is only one server is running at an instance of time.
:)

Comment: Yeah, I thought of a similar hack, using an additional custom id field, or alternatively - to avoid using `auto_increment` and have my Spark application assigning the id field by itself - but I would much rather do it in a straightforward way, as I think it should be done. I'm really baffled by the notion that it may not be possible to achieve.